# Why is function within main function in python always returning "none" when it should return a float?

Tags: python, function, type-conversion, minute

In order to learn python, I am trying to take a string from the user, convert this string in a float. I need to convert the minutes in a decimal number. This is what the "convert" function intends to do.

But I always get "none" as output. What is wrong?

```
   def main():
    
     time = input("what time is it?")
    
     def convert (a):

   #this split the string 

        x, z = time.split(":")
        x = float(x)
        z = float(z)

  #converts hours and minutes to float

        if z > 0:
           z = z / 60

  #converts minutes to decimals

        else:
          z = 0
          k = x + z
          return k
    
     result = convert(time)
     print(result)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Ok so when reviewing the whole thing, and using this code as follows, I have the error "expected an intended block after function definition on line 1".
This indentation stuff seems not easy.

```
def main():

time = input("what time is it?")

def convert (a):
    x, z = time.split(":")
    x = float(x)
    z = float(z)
    return x * (z / 60)
    

result = convert(time)
print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ok so now it finally works...after I placed a small indentation after the first "main" line, like so:

```
def main():

 time = input("what time is it?")

 def convert (a):
    x, z = time.split(":")
    x = float(x)
    z = float(z)
    return x * (z / 60)


 result = convert(time)
 print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There's no need to put `convert()` within `main()`. You'd be better off if they're two separate functions, with no nesting.

Comment: I understood from the learning assignment that I must nest. To be fully honest, why I would need a "main" function to start with is beyond me, but I follow the rules.

Comment: As an aside, having `if __name__ ==  "__main__":` call a function lets the .py file work as a top level script and as an imported module. The name "main" is somewhat arbitrary.  it could be that another python program tests your submission by importing and calling `main`.

Comment: I fixed the indentation in the answer. Give it a try. If it works, you can remove the new example from the question. BTW, it would be better to comment on the problem in the answer instead of duplicating it here. That way the poster can fix it.

Comment: Push that `time = ...` assignment over by four SPACEs, and you will have a well-formed `main()` function. Then move the `result = ...` and `print(result)` lines so they are directly under the `time = ...` assignment (same indent level), and `main()` will do what you want.

Comment: I did it slightly differently (just one space) but this seems to work. I wonder if there IDE or things like this that handle indentation automatically, because this was time wasted for not much I feel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are code paths in your function that do not reach the return statement. As per the Python semantics, when this happens, `None` is returned implicitly. Concretely, this happens when `z>0`. I assume you would want to fix the indentation of the return statement in the else branch. Looking at what you were trying to do, that seems like it would result in the correct behaviour. There is also a way to simplify your code, if you assume that inputs like "20:-10" would not occur, because that's the only way

```
def main():

    time = input("what time is it?")
  
    def convert (a):

       #this split the string 

       x, z = time.split(":")
       x = float(x)
       z = float(z)

       return x + z / 60

    result = convert(time)
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I indeed assume that "20:-10" will never occur. Even if in theory, it could, and I would need if I were to imagine this to have another "if" that would print "this is not allowed" to the user (but this was not part of the exercise).

Comment: @TomasMichel then there is no reason to check if `z > 0`. Even for if float(z) results in 0, dividing by 60 is still 0, so you can simplify you're code like I show in my answer. It might not work when you copy paste it because of pythons indentation rules. When you rewrite it, it should work as you expect it to.

Comment: Yes this makes sense...many thanks! I mean it make sense to not make things unnecessarily complicated with useless division

Comment: There is no real gain in only dividing by 60 if you need to. With how Python works, and all the overhead that happens between you writing x / 60, and it actually being calculated, the case when x is 0 is either already optimized, or the if statement makes it slower than just plainly dividing all the time. It's better to have a shorter, more easily understandable code! Be sure to accept one of the answers as well! Hope you get the things working now! Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is related to the scope and return value of the convert function. Specifically, the return statement is placed inside the else block, which means that if the condition if z > 0 is true, the function ends without hitting a return statement, thus returning None by default.

Comment: Many thanks but if I change the "return" indentation (placing it "before" the final "else"), then I get a "unindent does not match any outer indentation level",

Comment: @TomasMichel that should be the issue with somewhere else in your indentation. Ben is correct here. Try rewriting the same code once again, maybe you have missed a space somewhere.

Comment: Many thanks, I wish I could accept you answer as well!

Answer (score 2):

Because your function only returns something if the number of seconds it's equal to 0.
Indeed, you put the return of your function inside the else part of your if condition. So Unless it goes inside of it, it won't return anything.

Comment: Many thanks! I wish I could accept your answer as well!